# How can I configure nginx to only allow access on my home LAN or VPN?

Tags: nginx-config

I'm hosting Navidrome at home using nginx as a reverse proxy. My broadband provider uses a dynamic (but generally stable) IP address.  I have my own domain name which includes a dynamic DNS update service, so requests to mydomain.com resolve to the dynamic IP. I would like the site to be accessible - via the mydomain.com URL - from my home network either directly or when I use a VPN (wireguard), but to reject requests from the outside world.

The nginx server uses SSL, as it also serves up another site that is available externally. I don't want to disrupt that configuration (and SSL also means that just using the IP address of the server from inside my home network will cause problems for browsers and subsonic clients).

I tried adding

```
allow 192.168.0.0/24;
allow 10.13.13.0/24;
deny all;
```

to my nginx configuration but nginx is seeing any requests to mydomain.com from inside my LAN (or VPN) as coming from my dynamic IP address and returning http 403.

I could, I suppose, set up a DNS server at home and have mydomain.com point at the internal IP address of the server, but that's another moving part to maintain and if it breaks it would effectively knock out Internet access across the whole household.

So I think my only other solution is to have

```
allow aa.bb.cc.dd;
deny all;
```

where aa.bb.cc.dd is the dynamic IP, and to run a script that checks periodically for changes (using host mydomain.com or similar) and if the IP has changed, change the configuration file and bounce nginx.

I was wondering if I could do anything less clunky?